# Get the text from href with simple-html-dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I want to get the link text from an external website with simple-html-dom.
I use this code to get the href but I can´t get the html text.

```
foreach($html->find('div#left') as $e)
foreach($e->find('a') as $a)
 echo $a->href . '<br>';
 echo $a->text . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna change

```
foreach($html->find('div#left') as $e)
foreach($e->find('a') as $a)
 echo $a->href . '<br>';
 echo $a->text . '<br>';
```

to

```
foreach($html->find('div#left') as $e)
  foreach($e->find('a') as $a) {
    echo $a->href . '<br>';
    echo $a->text . '<br>';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I you want text from link use Magic Attributes "**[**innertext](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)****"

```
foreach($article5->find('a') as $i => $anchor)echo $anchor->innertext ;
```

Answer (score 0):

// Text for all links

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element){echo $element->innertext;}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.